Bochner-Minlos theorem for complex-valued cases
Let $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of real-valued Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $\Phi : \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$ be such that

$\Phi(0)=1$,
$\Phi$ is continuous at the origin
for all $n\ge 1$ and all $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$, the matrix $(\Phi(f_i-f_j))_{1\le i,j\le n}$ is Hermitian positive semidefinite.

Then, Bochner-Minlos theorem states that there exista a unique Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Phi(f)=\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})}e^{i\varphi(f)}\ d\mu(\varphi)\
\end{equation}
The text above is from an answer by Prof. Abdelmalek Abdesselam in MO.
In p.53-54 of Glimm-Jaffe book, a similar theorem is stated as well.
However, all these results are for real-valued (tempered) distributions, as the characteristic function of a random variable is usually for real-valued random variables only.
Now, my question is as follows:

Is it possible to extend the Bochner-Minlos theorem to complex-valued cases?

It seems that the characteristic function of a complex random variable can be defined. However, I can't find any further information on how to proceed.
Could anyone please help me?
Add) Perhaps, we may identify a complex random variable with a $2$D real random vector.

It's probably not the worst idea to include that $\mathscr{S}$ denotes the Schwartz space. The choice of font for the $S$ varies throughout the literature.

@M.G. Ok, I just did. Thank you for your comment.
